# A very simple game server using c#

Tags: c#

I just want to see a very simple sample of a c# game server that listens for connections from game client. Hope somebody can help me. I'm on the learning process of making a simple game server

Comment: There are tons of client server tutorials for c# out there. Just google for it.

Comment: ZeroMQ is quite good too.

Comment: Do you need a tcp/udp server for real time traffic or is the use of webservices enough for you?

Comment: "Where to start" questions are off-topic here. Please read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `TcpClient` like in the following example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C
Or, if you prefer to use `Socket` directly, there are some synchronous and asynchronous examples on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx

Those are generic examples, but they apply for games as well.

If you want to use a 3rd party lib, you could use Lidgren: http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/

PS: You didn't specify in what C# environment/version you want to create the game server. Because it might seem the same thing but it isn't. Windows, Windows Phone and Windows 8, for example, each one has it's own way of using networking (some may be shared but it's not a rule).